# Non-editable, Non-selectable Text Boxes in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios

This may sound like a stupid question, but I've been looking through the object library and can't seem to locate a proper Non-editable text box.

A label was the closest thing to it but the text always seems to stay centre left which is not what I want.

I'm thinking it's definitely the label, I just haven't figured out how to customize it properly.

I just want a box that I can fill with text so the text doesn't fly off the screen but always stays within the bounds of the box.

Thanks and sorry again if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an UITextView

```
UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = NO;
```

Edit: 
In swift:

```
var textView = UITextView.new();
textView.editable = false;
textView.selectable = false;
```

And FYI, an UILabel text alignment can be changed, eg :

```
var label = UILabel.new();
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: Thanks a mill! Just curious if this is possible in Storyboard? i.e- no code.

Comment: Sure, in IB you can open attribute inspector of UITextView, and in 'behavior', you have 2 checkboxes, "Editable", and "selectable".
For UITextField's alignment, there is an 'alignment' option, in its attributes inspector

Answer (score 0):

You can use UILabel (always read only). Yes Text will remain within its bounds and you can change text alignment. If you dont want the text to fly off the screen you or get your text truncated with a ... at the end (eg. xyz...) you need to set number of lines your label will use.

```
myInstanceOfUilabel.numberOfLines=3;
```

Make sure height of the label is tall enough to have the multiple lines displayed. Also for text alignment use

```
myInstanceOfUilabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

you can set them as:

```
   NSTextAlignmentLeft
   NSTextAlignmentCenter
   NSTextAlignmentRight
   NSTextAlignmentJustified
   NSTextAlignmentNatural
```

You can also do all this in storyboard without writing a single line of code. just by dragging in UILabel and setting its properties in inspector

But if you want to display text in a lot of lines and are not sure how long your strings are gonna be when you display at runtime then i'd suggest you use UITextView (can be set read only) and set it uneditable after instantiation.

```
myInstanceOfUitextview.editable=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextView has properties to turn off editing:

```
var textView = UITextView()

textView.isEditable = false
textView.isSelectable = false
```